GNU's AWK - Splitting Multibyte Character Strings w/Patsplit vs Split
I'd like to know if the following behavior is a reliable:
echo  | gawk '{split($0,array,"."); print array[1] length(array);}'

Output is: 1
vs
echo  | gawk '{patsplit($0,array,"."); print array[1] length(array);}'

Output is: �4
patsplit is working on bytes vs split on characters, but I haven't found this documented or discussed anywhere. Question is, can I count on this behavior and where?

This is because split and patsplit are fundamentally different functions.
split divides a string into fields by a field separator, i.e. what's between the fields, while patsplit divides a string into fields by matching fields themselves with a field pattern.
All gawk functions, including split and patsplit, work on locale-dependent characters, not bytes, per the documentation.
Also, a single-character string such as "." as a field separator is treated literally rather than as a regex pattern (see the documentation on FS).
Since there is no . in the input string of ,  when you call split with "." as the field separator, split sees only 1 field.
And since  consists of 4 bytes and presumably you have set your locale to a byte-based one such as C, when you call patsplit with "." as the field pattern, each . matches one byte of , producing an array of size 4.

I read  fieldsep, is a regexp describing where to split string on split from the GNU doc. Not sure why doc says it operates on characters, the character iswhich is 1 char and 4 bytes. I checked the src, in field.c in do_patsplit you can see it declared char *s; which is bytes.

Please check the linked documentation, where it says "gawk understands locales (see Where You Are Makes a Difference) and does all string processing in terms of characters, not bytes." The C declaration can be char *s; as long as it is processed as locale-aware characters.

I did read that, but it doesn't seem to be true.

Again, just because the parameter type is char * it doesn't mean it is logically processed byte by byte. If you follow the code you'll see that it calls fpat_parse_field, which in turns calls research, which processes the string as characters with all the LC-aware helper functions in regcomp.c.

Right, I guess it's consistent. I switched the split separator to the empty string "" and both return the byte count with LC_ALL=C and the character count with LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8. Maybe the documentation could make it more clear.

I don't think the documentation needs to be any clearer since by stating that all strings are processed as locale-aware characters rather than bytes it is already established that characters are equivalent to bytes when you set LC_CTYPE as C (which belongs to the documentation of locale).

When you have a multi-byte character and set LC_ALL to C you are reading bytes at that point. It's a semantic dance, the documentation probably reflects support for multi-byte chars as an after-thought.

this is likely a bug on gawk's part.
